# If you sample a function at n random points, what is the expected error of the mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a continuous function with domain and range [0,1] (And thats all you know about the function). If I sample this function n times at uniformly random points of [0,1], and take the mean of the function values at the sample points, what is the expected absolute difference from this and the actual mean of the function?

If this is not possible to know, is it possible to know in the case that the function is known to be of physical experimental origin so does not likely have any weird mathematical properties?

Comment: That's pretty hard to calculate. Are you sure you need the expected absolute difference from the mean and can't make do with the usual root mean square difference?

Comment: rms will be just as fine, didnt know that was simpler

Comment: This might be relevant https://people.orie.cornell.edu/pfrazier/Presentations/2011.11.INFORMS.Tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root mean square difference of the sample mean of a sample of size $n$ from the actual mean is $n^{-\frac12}$ times the standard deviation of the function $f$, that is,

$$
\sqrt{\frac1n\left(\int_0^1f(x)^2\mathrm dx-\left(\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx\right)^2\right)}\;.
$$